# can i calculate image size from given dimensions. i want to show estimated size on dimensions change

Tags: jquery, image-processing, crop

i want to display image size based on the changed image dimensions when user starts to crop the newly uploaded image in file field. I am displaying a preview of image as user selects an image from file, here user can crop image. As user starts croping i want to display estimated image size based on the new dimensions of crop size. i know the file's original size and dimensions and as  well new dimensions of crop size. 
Is there a way so that i can calculate size based on this information.
here is some code about the scenario so that it could be more clear.
html code
     get('item_picture')->getValue();
        if (is_array($return)) {
            $return = ($this->picture->item_picture) ? $this->picture->item_picture : '';
        }
        ?>
        
             Image
            
                " data-provides="fileupload">

```
                <?php if ($return != '') { ?>
                    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px; line-height: 20px;">
                        <a data-gallery="" class="gallery-item" href="<?php echo $this->webUrl('/uploads/items/' . $return . '?' . time()); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->webUrl('/uploads/items/' . $return); ?>" style="max-height:350px;" /></a>
                    </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" class="fileupload-new thumbnail">
                        <img alt="" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px; line-height: 20px;">
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div>
                    <span class="btn btn-file">
                        <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
                        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                        <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('item_picture')) ?>
                    </span>
                    <a class="btn hide" id="startCrop">Crop</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" >Remove</a>
                    <code class="fileupload-exists">Size:</code> <span class="fileupload-exists" id="file_size"></span>
                    <!-- updated size would be updated here in a label -->
                    <p id="image1-dim" class="label label-success" style="display:none;">

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <code>Max allowed size: </code> 1024KB <br>
            <code>Allowed Cropping Area</code>Allowed Cropping area is proportion of 600x400px<br />
            <code>NOTE! </code>
            Attached image thumbnail is supported in Latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer 10 only 
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container" class="input">
            <input type="hidden" class="x" name="logo_x" id="x" />
            <input type="hidden" class="y" name="logo_y" id="y"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="w" name="logo_w" id="w"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="h" name="logo_h" id="h"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in jQuery on start crop this function triggers 
     $(document).on('click', '#startCrop', function(e) {

```
    var image = $('.cropbox');

    var originalWidth = image[0].naturalWidth;
    var originalHeight = image[0].naturalHeight;
    $('.cropbox').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200,
        onSelectChange: updateCoords,
        imageHeight: originalHeight,
        imageWidth: originalWidth,
        aspectRatio: '3:2',
        maxHeight: 400,
        maxWidth: 600,
        parent: '#media-panel'
    });
    $("#image1-dim").html('width: 0, height: 0');
    $("#image1-dim").show();

});
function updateCoords(img, selection)
{
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;
    var size = $('input[name="item_picture"]')[0].files[0].size;
    var image = $('.cropbox');
    var originalWidth = image[0].naturalWidth;
    var originalHeight = image[0].naturalHeight;
    //        alert(originalHeight);
    $('#x').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y').val(selection.y1);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);
    $("#image1-dim").html('width: ' + selection.width + ', height: ' + selection.height);

    // here i want to write some logic to calculate estimated size using available info. privious dimensions and size, new crop dimensions 
}
```

Remember that image is in preview just crop dimensions are drawn over it, not processed yet.

Comment: Please be more specific... the short answer is yes. Preferable add some code with what you explain to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you asking about number of pixels (trivial to calculate) or filesize (harder to estimate)?  I assume you're asking about the latter.

Comment: i have updated the my question i hope it create some sense

Comment: #Glenn Randers-Pehrson yes i am asking about file size